# google app engine Bigtable

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa, google-cloud-datastore

I have doubt using jpa. I defined the datanucleus connection for MYSQL as follows.

```
datanucleus.ConnectionDriverName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
datanucleus.ConnectionURL=jdbc:mysql://localhost/myDB
datanucleus.ConnectionUserName=...
datanucleus.ConnectionPassword=..
```

My constraint is if I want to connect to google app engine datastore(ie Big table) via jpa
how to give the above connection for bigtable.

Comment: you should really accept some of your answered questions, if you want people to answer this one

Comment: Agree with Valentin, I really can't see much point in answering your questions when you give no credit. Not that this question makes much sense either ... persisting to BigTable or MySQL ... time to decide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to configure any settings in order to persist to Bigtable using JPA - just run it inside the App Engine environment, and it ought to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps [jiql](http://www.jiql.org/xwiki/bin/view/Main/) would be useful.